# Reuploading new app to markets

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, react-native

I have an Ionic 2 app at Play Market and AppStore. Now I develop with React-Native. Can I replace my Ionic app by React-Native app in markets? Does App Store/Google Play permit it?

Comment: Of course.  Why wouldn't you be able to?  Google doesn't care what technology you use.

Comment: I know that AppStore is checking binary code of your app

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definitely allow to upload but just make sure you upgrade your app's version code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove the app from Itunes Connect if you want but you can just submit the whole project as an update to apple store with a new version.